# Make failed while making sdk after building android source

Tags: android, android-source, android-sdk-tools

I am creating a system service and api on an android source and i compiled and built it. And it ran with no problem on the device. These are the commands I gave.

```
make update-api
make -j8
```

This built and ran it on the device. No problem. I wanted to create an app for the system service so I tried to make the sdk.
    make sdk -j8
It did not work. I gave lunch command.

```
lunch sdk-eng
make sdk -j8
```

Still fails to build. Now this is the error I get at the end.

```
frameworks/base/core/res/res/xml/storage_list_box.xml:47: error: Error: No resource found that matches the given name (at 'storageDescription' with value '@string/storage_nand_flash').

make: *** [out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk] Error 1
make: *** Deleting file `out/target/common/obj/APPS/framework-res_intermediates/package-export.apk'

#### make failed to build some targets (01:06 (mm:ss)) ####
```

This happened twice. And I had to start from scratch. Now I am stuck again. I dont want to start from scratch each time I get this error. Please shed some light on what I might be doing wrong.

Answer (score 1):

Write this command:

```
source build/envsetup.sh; lunch aosp_arm-eng; make -j8 ; source build/envsetup.sh; lunch sdk-eng; make sdk
```

And wait patiently.

Comment: Thanks for replying again. Appreciate it. I got the same error while doing make -j8 now.

Comment: http://www.linaro.org/blog/adding-a-new-system-service-to-android-5-tips-and-how-to/
I am using this link to work with. In it, it says. 
"TIP:  After building the SDK, you cannot build frameworks/base/ alone anymore, you will get

make: *** No rule to make target out/target/product/jetson/system/framework/framework-res.apk’

You can overcome this with

$ mmma frameworks/base

but it takes a long time, otherwise build frameworks-res alone, then rebuild frameworks

$ mmm frameworks/base/core/res
$ mmm frameworks/base"
But I tried doing that but doing that also fails.